# Why TextView.text is empty

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

In my iOS app I have ViewController with Label and TextView. Both of them have no text by default. In viewWillAppear method of ViewController I check - if they are empty - I put some strings from server in those Label and TextView. It works fine and I see this strings on the screen.

But when I open this ViewController again and viewWillAppear method runs again - it still thinks that myTextView.text is empty and tries to get data from server. myLabel.text works absolutely like I expect - it's text value is not empty.

I checked outlet name of TextView it is correct.

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)
       if (myTextView.text.isEmpty) {
          NSLog("myTextView is empty - need to refresh data") 
          updateStrings() }
  }

  func updateStrings () { 
        ..... get data from server ....
            myTextView.text = string_from_server
            myLabel.text = string_from_server
            }
```

Comment: Can you post the code which you have implemented?

Comment: how are you loading this controller in memory..? Is it reloaded..? for the second time put a breakpoint in viewdidload and if it is called again then your controller is loaded again.

Comment: i added code that i implemented

Comment: I assume the _get-data-from-server_ part happens on a background thread, and I don't see you'd come back to the main-thread for updating the UI.

Comment: it is updating UI correctly

Comment: @moonvader, in that case what is your problem...?

Comment: @holex the problem is that each time i open this view - it thinks that textview is empty and asks for data from server. I am starting to think that mmdrawer that i am using - is the reason for this problem.

Comment: @moonvader, in that case stop using _mmdrawer_, if you are insecure about how a 3rd party stuff works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly, the code you have posted doesn't look like it's the code you're using - this won't compile.  You need to close the quotes on the NSLog, and you need to unwrap the optional on the TextView text.

Here's a version of the same function which does work as required

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if (myTextView.text!.isEmpty)
    {
        NSLog("myTextView is empty - need to refresh data")
        myTextView.text = "Hello World"  // or updateStrings()
    }
}
```

Are you reloading this view controller, or are you creating a new instance of it each time?

Comment: You are right - this is shorten version of my code. I use MMDrawerController to show view.